# Calling a company for an interview decision

Tags: job-offer, internship

I'm involved in a coop program at my school and after receiving a job offer, you must accept it in 24 or it is considered to be declined. I received an offer today from Company A.

Previously I'd interviewed at Company B, where I'd much rather work at and they said they would let me know the result of my interview this week.

Should I call the student program coordinator at Company B and let them know of this situation and ask them when their decision will be finalized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- Take your chances that Company B lets you know in next 24 hours.
- Tell Company B the situation.  Express you would rather work there.
- Ask Company A if you can have until the end of the week.  But then if
  Company B does not get back to you this week you are in the same
  spot.

I see no problem with letting Company B know the situation. Especially given there is student program coordinator to call.  If they are interested in you then they would not want to lose you to timing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have anything to lose especially at this starting time of your career path. What is the worst that can happen. They say they haven't decided yet. If this is the word, are you going to wait for this Company B where you set your heart on or go for the Company A, the sure thing ? Call them and take any answer that doesn't say, "we decided to hire you" as a "NO" and go with company A. Welcome to the big league, where you will have to make so many unfavorable decisions and learn to live with them. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is important to inform Company B that you have an offer deadline and would like them to expedite your job application. You do not have to reveal the details of Company A's offer unless you are trying to negotiate a better offer (Since this is a co-op, you probably don't have room to negotiate).

If Company B does not expedite your job application, you have to make a hard decision of whether to wait for Company B or accept Company A.